# Is there a way to auto-size pictures when placing them in code using HTML?

Tags: html, image

So I am making a biography page in HTML and I have to place a picture in it. This is the code that I have:

```
<img src = "IMG_148672786044453.jpeg" height = "281" width = "179"
         alt = "picture of me"/>
```

This is after I have re-sized it. Is there a way to auto-size it to get a good size.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "auto-size it to get a good size"?

Comment: If you just set the width of the image and remove the height. the height will "auto-size" with the same image ratio. I don't know if thats what you need. Same happens vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7xvqn85/)

```
<p>
  <a href="MY WEBSITE LINK" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQuQ1LDwNtA8y5pylsvvBcWPBazSue1uPsFiBbUEghPBd9QrRmXSG7itA" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
  </a>
</p>
```

This should scale your image if in a fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should do all image "sizing" in your CSS along with other changes to the visual presentation of your html. Add a class to your image tag, "bio-image" for example, and style it in your CSS like so:

```
.bio-image {
    width: 179px //px scale of your image relative to its width
}
```

You can scale relative to its height by replacing "width" with "height"